# Trying to get imge id in web method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, ado.net

I am trying to access image upload value means image value at server side from
client side, in a webmethod i am passing the value of the image from client through ajax to webmethod at server side.
 dynamic table where image upload is a part in that table

```
 $("#pdfFormInsideTblRight").after("<table class='table table-bordered'><thead class='thead-inverse'><tr><th class='text-left'>Properties</th>" +
                        "<th>Detail</th></tr></thead>" +
                        "<tr><td class='text-left'><strong>Product Group</strong></td>" +
    "<td><input type='file' id='flImage' name='flImage[]' multiple /></td>
</tr></table>");
```

and now i want to store the image uploaded above in variable 'flImage', in a variable 'user' like other inputs value from textbox and lables value are stored through jquery in var 'user' as given below and passs it through ajax to server side.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "[id*=btnFrmSubmit]", function () {
    var user = {};
                user.PRODUCT_ID = 1;
    user.REVISION = $("#Revision").text();
    user.P_GROUP = $("[id*=P_Group]").val();
    user.IMG1 = $("#flImage")[0].files;
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "TDC.aspx/SaveFrmDetails",
                data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
                //data:  JSON.stringify({user:user}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("User has been added successfully.");
                    window.location.reload();
                }                
            });
            return false;

     });
    }
```

and now in web method i want to access 'imag' which is futher used but 'flImage' is showing error "'flImage' doesn't exist in current context" so how to resolve this error.  `System.Drawing.Image imag = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(flImage.PostedFile.InputStream);`

Webmethod part

```
[WebMethod]    
    public static void SaveFrmDetails(User user)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conndbprodnew"].ConnectionString;
 System.Drawing.Image imag = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(flImage.PostedFile.InputStream);
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO TDC_PRODUCT1(PRODUCT_ID,TDC_NO, REVISION,REVISION_DATE,P_GROUP,PROD_DESC,N_I_PRD_STD,APPLN,FRM_SUPP,CREATED_DATE,CREATED_BY,IMG1) VALUES (:PRODUCT_ID,:TDC_NO,:REVISION,:REVISION_DATE,:P_GROUP,:PROD_DESC,:N_I_PRD_STD,:APPLN,:FRM_SUPP,:CREATED_DATE,:Created_By,:IMG1)", con))
            {                
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":PRODUCT_ID", user.PRODUCT_ID);
                 .                                                                               .                                                                               .
cmd.Parameters.Add("IMG1", OracleType.Blob, 0).Value = ConvertImageToByteArray(imag, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to convert lastline

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("IMG1", OracleType.Blob, 0).Value = ConvertImageToByteArray(imag, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

in `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()` format. like other parameters have been added above.

Comment: read this article https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm it talks about Raw and Long and LOB

Comment: @MethodManit's but my concern is how can i getvalue of user.IMG1 = $("#flImage")[0].files; passed through ajax webService in SaveFrmDetails webmethod and used at System.Drawing.Image imag = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(flImage.PostedFile.InputStream); i mean exactly what should be placed before "PostedFile.InputStream" inside  System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(flImage.PostedFile.InputStream);

Comment: @MethodMan here i am trying to explain what i want to convey exactly.Please guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672787/storing-image-in-a-variable-and-passing-it-through-ajax-webservice-to-push-into